# Why is my Outlook Harmon.ie sidebar detached?

Tags: harmon.ie

When selecting "Show Sidebar" on the Outlook toolbar, it appears but is detached from Outlook. The space where it should be is just a grey box and I can't find a way to park it back in that space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in another similar question:
Open Outlook settings, under "General", choose "Optimize for compatibility" option, then restart Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility mode is needed as detailed at: https://harmon.ie/KB/harmonie-grayed